# foreach php dentro de <script>

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

Poderiam me informar se é errado a utilização deste código assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php foreach ($lista as $key => $value) { 
  $id_indicador = $lista[$key]['id'];
?>
    var id_indicador = <?php echo $id_indicador ?>;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#collapse"+id_indicador+"1").click(function() {
        $("#collapse"+id_indicador).load('indicadores.php?id_indicador='+id_indicador);
        setTimeout( function(){ 
           $('.tooltips-grafico'+id_indicador).tooltip('show');
    }, 3000);
      });
      $('.tooltips-grafico'+id_indicador).on('hide.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
      return false;
      });
    }); <?php } ?> </script>
```

Comment: Isso não faz muito sentido pois vais estar a escrever no HTML/script `var id_indicador` várias vezes, e isso faz com que a variável seja rescrita. E a repetir imenso código desnecessáriamente. Podes explicar o que pretendes fazer? Parece-me que passares essa array/objeto do PHP para uma array/objeto em javascript seria melhor, e depois iterar no javascript.

Comment: Talvez seja interessante isto que falou, porém, não sei como passar o array/objeto para array/objeto em javascript. Poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Realmente não tem lógica, uma vez que _Javascript_ e _PHP_ operam em lados diferentes. Podes sempre solicitar os valores ao _PHP_, e coloca-los no _loop_.

Comment: Poderiam me auxiliar então passar o array/objeto para array/objeto em javascript?

Comment: Explica melhor o que pretendes fazer ao certo. Com base nesse script que passaste não dá para entender muito.

Comment: Antes o código era assim: https://jsfiddle.net/g273jq25/.  Porém, a cada novo indicador, tenho que adicionar os códigos manualmente. Desta forma que estou tentando, queria trazer os códigos de todos os indicadores no array, e gerar automaticamente o código javascript.

Comment: Tens aí a parte que contém o HTML ?

Comment: Acho que entendi. Pode resolver somente com javascript/jquery.. vou postar como resposta.

Comment: ok. No aguardo.

Comment: atualizei o HTML aqui https://jsfiddle.net/g273jq25/2/

Comment: Pessoal, alguém conseguiu algo?

Comment: quer serviço expresso ? ...   "ok, no aguardo" soaria melhor como , "por favor obrigado".. e "pessoal, alguém conseguiu?" nem deveria existir...

Comment: então? cadê o feedback? passou 12 minutos.. rsrsrs, estou no aguardo

Comment: Desculpe o constrangimento Daniel. Não queria parecer rude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Particularmente eu faria dessa forma:

```
<a href="" onClick="get_indicador(<?=$row['id'];?>)">Visualizar</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function get_indicador(id){

        var id_indicador = id;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#collapse"+id_indicador+"1").click(function() {
                $("#collapse"+id_indicador).load('indicadores.php?id_indicador='+id_indicador);
                setTimeout( function(){ 
                $('.tooltips-grafico'+id_indicador).tooltip('show');
            }, 3000);
        });
            $('.tooltips-grafico'+id_indicador).on('hide.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
                return false;
            });
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Funciona também. Não está errado. Mas nesse caso, o document.ready é desnecessário. Uma desvantagem dessa técnica é deixar o código HTML "sujo". Outro ponto é que o trecho `$("#collapse"+id_indicador+"1")` diverge do segundo código que o AP postou onde mostra que a concatenação não é sempre o número 1.

Comment: Sim, verdade... Foi apenas uma sugestão

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância amigos, porém, sou bem fraco na questão de javascript. Estou tentando da forma que mostrou neste código, porém, mesmo assim não consigo fazer funcionar. O meu código, da forma que está, mesmo estando torto, é o mais próximo que cheguei de fazer funcionar. O estranho dele é que apenas o último 'accordion' funciona corretamente e chama o método load. Independente de quantos indicadores eu carrego, sempre é o último que funciona.

Comment: Cara, me equivoquei. Está totalmente certa sua resposta. Precisei apenas de uns ajustes e funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

É mais fácil usar a função `json_encode` do PHP. Aí, no JavaScript, é só fazer o tratamento do `array` convertido para `JSON`.

Exemplo:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Como posso tratar isto no javascript Henrique? teria algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de como percorrer uma sequência de IDs.

A mágica começa nesse ponto `list = $('[id^=foo]');`.

Com isso, obtém um array de objetos cujo ID começa com "foo".

Com o array em mãos, basta brincar com as informações e automatizar todos os outros processos relacionados com o número que compõe o ID.

O exemplo abaixo é apenas um toggle(). Troque-o pelas ações que deseja implementar.

O código é simples e procurei montar algo genérico e similar ao código da pergunta.

```js
$().ready(function() {

 /**
 Procura todos os IDS que começam com "foo".
 */
 list = $('[id^=foo]');

 /**
 Verifica o tamanho do array. Se for maior que ZERO, indica que encontrou objetos.
 */
 if(list.length > 0){

  /**
  Laço de repetição para iterar o array. Equivalente ao foreach() do PHP.
  */
  $.each(list, function(key, row) {

   /**
   Extrai o número do ID
   */
   num = row.id.replace(/\D/g, '');

   /**
   Imprime os resultados no console.
   No Google Chrome, pressione CTRL+SHIT+I para ver o console.
   */
   console.log('key: '+key+', id: '+row.id, num);

   $('#bar'+num).click(function() {

    /**
    Extrai o número do ID
    */
    num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');

    /**
    Exibe ou oculta o objeto relacionado com ID do objeto clicado.
    */
    $('#foo'+num).toggle();

       /**
       Exibe o número clicado, no console.
       */
    console.log(num);
   });

   /**
   Oculta os objetos "foo".
   */
   $('#'+row.id).toggle();
  });
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bar1">bar</div>
<div id="foo1">foo</div>
<div id="bar2">bar</div>
<div id="foo2">foo</div>
<div id="bar3">bar</div>
<div id="foo3">foo</div>
<div id="bar4">bar</div>
<div id="foo4">foo</div>
<div id="bar5">bar</div>
<div id="foo5">foo</div>
```

No seu código será um pouco complicado usar essa lógica sem modificar o padrão do ID do elemento que recebe o click.

Nos elementos chamados "collapse" que recebem o trigger de click(), sugiro modificar para outro nome como "bar_collapse"+numero.

O número deve ser idêntico ao outro elemento "collapse" que invoca o método load().

Exemplo

```
<div id="bar_collapse1">
<div id="collapse1"></div>
</div>
<div id="bar_collapse2">
<div id="collapse2"></div>
</div>
```

Isso é necessário para facilitar o momento de busca dos objetos `list = $('[id^=bar_collapse]');`

Answer (score 0):

Olha esse exemplo:

```
return json_encode($arr);
```

O array impresso `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "sua_url.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
            alert(value.a + " - " + value.c);
        });
    }
});
```

nesse exemplo quero o valor da chave a e c.